# kivy mapview on screenmanager

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have tried first my mapview function with only the mapview in the build which worked, but I had to return in the build mapview. Then I tried having the mapview on my first screen, and I face problems with it:

```
    import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label as label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.button import Button as button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout as gl
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput as ti
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapMarkerPopup
import os




kivy.require("1.11.1")

#first screen page
class Mapspage(Screen,MapView,gl):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=1
        marker=MapMarkerPopup(lat=55.6928595,lon=12.5992828)
        self.abouting=button(text="lil'mermaid")
        self.abouting.bind(on_press=self.pressbutton())
        marker.add_widget(self.abouting)
        mapview=MapView(zoom=12, lat=55.6712674, lon=12.5938239)
        mapview.add_marker(marker)
    def pressbutton(self):
        chatapp.screenmanager.current="About"
#button leads to about page
class Aboutpage(Screen,gl):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=1
        self.message=label(text="yup dissapointingly small",halign="center",valign="middle",fontsize=30)
        self.message.bind(width=self.utw())
        self.add_widget(self.message)
    def utw(self, *_):
        self.message.text_size=(self.message.width*0.9,None)
        #updatetextwidth
    
class Epicapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screenmanager=ScreenManager()
        
        self.mapspage=Mapspage()
        screen=Screen(name="places")
        screen.add_widget(self.mapspage)
        self.screenmanager.add_widget(screen)
        
        self.aboutpage=Aboutpage()
        screen=Screen(name="About")
        screen.add_widget(self.aboutpage)
        self.screenmanager.add_widget(screen)
        

        return self.screenmanager


if __name__=="__main__":
    chatapp=Epicapp()
    chatapp.run()
```

I get as an error message this:

```
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-4a0782fed14b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/pi/Documents/learningkivy.py', wdir='/home/pi/Documents')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 678, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 106, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/pi/Documents/learningkivy.py", line 70, in <module>
    chatapp.run()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run
    root = self.build()

  File "/home/pi/Documents/learningkivy.py", line 54, in build
    self.mapspage=Mapspage()

  File "/home/pi/Documents/learningkivy.py", line 28, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 265, in __init__
    super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kw)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
    super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  File "/home/pi/.kivy/garden/garden.mapview/mapview/view.py", line 526, in __init__
    self.add_widget(self._scatter)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 139, in add_widget
    pos_hint=self._trigger_layout)

  File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 419, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind

AssertionError: None is not callable
```

Not really helpfull error message, but I am guessing it is not happy with the

> `super.__init__`

function, yet without it, it will not know about the about page.

Comment: Rather than extending `Screen`, `MapView`, and`GridLayout` in one class, (not to mention that `Screen` already extends `RelativeLayout`), try creating a `Screen` that contains a `MapView`, perhaps as a child of a `GridLayout`.

Comment: im not sure i understand. If I have screen not inherited then the program will tell me it doesnt know about the About page ´ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "About".´ yet if no mapview in the class then it will not be able to add widget like my map marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version of your code that mostly works:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label as label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.button import Button as button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapMarkerPopup

kivy.require("1.11.1")


# first screen page
class Mapspage(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Mapspage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        gl = GridLayout(cols=1)
        marker = MapMarkerPopup(lat=55.6928595, lon=12.5992828)
        self.abouting = button(text="lil'mermaid")
        self.abouting.bind(on_press=self.pressbutton)
        mapview = MapView(zoom=12, lat=55.6712674, lon=12.5938239)
        mapview.add_marker(marker)
        gl.add_widget(mapview)
        gl.add_widget(self.abouting)
        self.add_widget(gl)

    def pressbutton(self, *args):
        chatapp.screenmanager.current = "About"


# button leads to about page
class Aboutpage(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Aboutpage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        gl = GridLayout(cols=1)
        self.message = label(text="yup dissapointingly small", halign="center", valign="middle", font_size=30)
        self.message.bind(width=self.utw)
        gl.add_widget(self.message)
        self.add_widget(gl)

    def utw(self, *_):
        self.message.text_size = (self.message.width * 0.9, None)
        # updatetextwidth


class Epicapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screenmanager = ScreenManager()

        self.mapspage = Mapspage(name="places")
        self.screenmanager.add_widget(self.mapspage)

        self.aboutpage = Aboutpage(name="About")
        self.screenmanager.add_widget(self.aboutpage)

        return self.screenmanager


if __name__ == "__main__":
    chatapp = Epicapp()
    chatapp.run()
```

A couple notes about errors encountered in your original code:

- When you use `bind` or `on_press` (or any event binding) you should bind to a method. If you bind to something like `self.utw()`, you are executing the `self.utw()` method and trying to bind to whatever that method returns. You should bind to the method, not its return, like this: `self.message.bind(width=self.utw)`.
- In a `Label`, the font size is set using `font_size` not `fontsize`.

In the above code, `MapsPage` is a `Screen` that contains a `GridLayout`. That `GridLayout` contains a `MapView` and a `Button`.

The `AboutPage` is also a `Screen`, and it contains a `GridLayout` that contains a `Label`.

The `build()` method is simplified, since both `MapsPage` and `AboutPage` are `Screens`, there is no need to create additional `Screens` just to contain them.

The error message in your post is caused by the `self.pressbutton()` call in the `__init__()` method of `MapsPage`.

Comment: omg the gl.add_widget and self.add_widget(gl) does miracles! :DDDD thankyou im still learning and very much in the beginning. i removed the gl.add_wiget(self.abouting) and added back marker.add_widget(self.abouting) so that the button appears when clicking the marker on the map (which i thouhgt was a sexy design in kivy)